# Remove selected dynamic checked items from listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Here, in a **listview** I have added a custom row in which `Checkbox` and `EditText` are there and with a `add` button I just add multiple views to my **listview**. Adding is working perfectly but when it comes to **removing** part the checked items are not removing and apart from that suppose I selected two items, then two items from last deleted. I don't know whats going on with my code please help me.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AdapterCustom customAdapter;
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<Integer> listOfItemsToDelete;
AdapterCustom.ViewHolder item;
int POS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listOfItemsToDelete = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    customAdapter = new AdapterCustom(MainActivity.this, R.layout.main, stringArrayList);
}

public void addItems(View v) {
    stringArrayList.add("");
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeItems(View v) {

    if (listOfItemsToDelete.isEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No items selected.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        Log.i("Delete Pos", POS + "");

        if (!listOfItemsToDelete.equals("")) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listOfItemsToDelete.size(); j++) {
                stringArrayList.remove(listOfItemsToDelete.get(j) - j);
                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**AdapterCustom.java**

```
public class AdapterCustom extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;


    ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;
    MainActivity activity;


    public AdapterCustom(Context context, int resourceId, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        super(context, resourceId, arrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.stringArrayList = arrayList;
        positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(stringArrayList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArrayList.size(); i++) {
            positionArray.add(false);
        }
        activity = new MainActivity();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stringArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return stringArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        EditText ediText;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            item = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main, null);

            item.ediText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ediText);
            item.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            item.checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));
            convertView.setTag(item);
            final View finalConvertView1 = convertView;
            item.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                    if (b) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) compoundButton.getTag();
                        POS = getPosition;
                        listOfItemsToDelete.add(POS);
                        Log.i("position after check", POS + "");
                        Log.i("position check array", listOfItemsToDelete + "");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            item = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        item.checkBox.setTag(position);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:onClick="addItems"
        android:text="Add New Item" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:onClick="goItems"
        android:text="Go to Item" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="removeItems"
    android:text="Remove Item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**`main.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/custom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp"
android:weightSum="10">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ediText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:hint="Type Anything You Want" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try to change `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` with `customAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);` ?

Comment: there is no such thing notifyRemoved i think

Comment: notifyItemRemoved() method is in recyclerView. not in listview

Comment: oops sorry I thought that we are talking about recycle view, because nobody uses listviews anymore :)

Comment: @Vassilis Pallas can you please help me with RecyclerView I implemented this but in list view we can set Tag to View and getTag when CheckBox is checked but in RecyclerView  am not getting the exact path to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You only remove the item from the array. Try removing the item also from the list view adapter with  adapter.remove(itemPosition);

Comment: Same thing happened Razvan

Answer (score 0):

What does mean

```
 - j
```

in this code:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < listOfItemsToDelete.size(); j++) {
            stringArrayList.remove(listOfItemsToDelete.get(j) - j);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

?

I think that:

```
    for (String itemToRemove:listOfItemsToDelete) {
        stringArrayList.remove(itemToRemove);
    }

    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listOfItemsToDelete.clear();
```

would be appropriate.

Comment: **String itemToRemove ?** i just used this `for (Integer itemToRemove:listOfItemsToDelete) { stringArrayList.remove(itemToRemove); } customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); listOfItemsToDelete.clear();` But still does not working

Comment: how you update `listOfItemsToDelete`   in your MainActivity?

Comment: I just took an Integer ArrayList to store position of Checked item Position and add to the array list.